# URL rewriting with Django

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, url, apache2

The Problem I want to solve is the following: 
E.g. we have https://example.com/?id=e46Hd3cDe. But I want to make it look nicer so I want users to be able to go to this link: https://example.com/e46Hd3cDe and get the same HTML file returned.

How could I achieve this in Django?
If I would have to change something in the Apache config, how could I do that while testing Django locally? Currently, I test my Django website by calling `python manage.py runserver` and opening it at localhost:8000.

Comment: That is the way django normally works. Just write a URL pattern.

Comment: But how? It doesn't automatically rewrite it you if you enter ?id=3737332 or something else as the query. Do you know a source where I can learn how to do that?

Comment: But "rewriting" is not a relevant concept here. You design the URLs however you want. If you want the URL to be just the ID, then put that in the urls.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django, in your `urls.py`, define in `url_patterns`:

```
url_patterns = [
    path('/<int:id>', view_name_goes_here),
]
```

Then, configure the corresponding functions in your `views.py` to accept the `id` parameter and get the corresponding object.

You don't need to modify your Apache config beyond adding in the `WGSI` setup for Django.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! But how can I then get the int in my views? Can I just get it as another parameter, in e.g. `def myView(request, id):`? Or would I split the URI and read it from there? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes, @GeorgeWalt. Here's the explanation from the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/.